# If I have the eigenvalues, can I find the corresponding eigenvectors?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, eigenvalues

The eigenvectors ($\psi _i$) of the following matrix are rather complicated
$$
\rho =\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 G_+ & k & k & G_- \\
 k & L_+ & L_- & k \\
 k & L_- & L_+ & k \\
 G_- & k & k & G_+ \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
So, I want to suppose that $ E_i $ is the eigenvalue of $\rho$ that corresponding to the eigencfunction $\psi _i$, then to evaluate ($\psi _i$) as a function of $E_i $.

Is there a way I can do this with Mathematica?

Comment: Is your matrix purely symbolic? Or do the variables have numeric values?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assume your matrix is

```
ρ ={{p, k, k, m},
    {k, a, b, k},
    {k, b, a, k},
    {m, k, k, p}};
```

and you have found eigenvalues using

```
Eigenvalues[ρ]
```

And for some reason, you do not like `Eigensystem`. Then you can use the `NullSpace` command

```
NullSpace[ρ - (a - b) IdentityMatrix[4]]
NullSpace[ρ - (p - m) IdentityMatrix[4]]
```

to recover the eigenvectors corresponding to eigenvalues $E_1=a-b$, and $E_2=p-m$, etc.